# Array texture in OpenGL 3.+ with mipmap

Tags: c++, opengl-3

I have read this tutorial: [Array Texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture),
but I don't want to use the glTexStorage3D()(requires OpenGL 4.2) function. First of all, can someone check whether I have implemented this code properly(I'm using glTexImage3D instead of glTexStorage3D):

```
unsigned int nrTextures = 6;
GLsizei width = 256;
GLsizei height = 256;
GLuint arrayTextureID;
std::vector<unsigned char*> textures(nrTextures);

//textures: Load textures here...

glGenTextures(1, &arrayTextureID);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, arrayTextureID);

//Gamma to linear color space for each texture.
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_SRGB, width, height, nrTextures, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < nrTextures; i++)
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textures[i]);

/*glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);*/
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

/*glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);*/

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
```

How do I implement mipmapping with this implementation?

Comment: "I have read this tutorial" That's not a tutorial; that's documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mostly looks ok. The only problem I can see is that `GL_SRGB` is not a valid internal texture format. So the `glTexImage3D()` call needs to use `GL_SRGB8` instead:

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL_SRGB8, width, height, nrTextures, 0,
             GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

For generating mipmaps, you can call:

```
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);
```

after you filled the texture with data with the `glTexSubImage3D()` calls.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction! And I need to change from glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) to glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR) ? Mipmapping will be applied to all the textures? thanks again!